# Twitching brushless motor when RC (PWM) servo input given through microprocessor

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, microprocessor

I am a young hobbyist.

I am currently working on an RC project with fixed-wing aircraft. The goal of the project is to use an ESP32-based microprocessor (it is not ESP32, a card named Deneyap) to apply some flight controls to the system via an autopilot / RC input. Basically, it's a homemade autopilot. We will use this in a upcoming contest.

The current state of the project:

- I have two different power sources: USB and 3s 25c LiPo (11.1 V - 12.4 V).
- There are 1 reciever (Rx), 1 radio controller (Fly Sky i6x with 10 ch, Tx), 4 servo motors (Tower Pro SG90, 180deg) 1 ESC (brandless 30A), 1 brushless motor (brandless 1400kV). and some sensors with an I2C connection.
- I am basically taking ppm signal from Rx, and analysing its signals in interrupts, dividing it into 8 channel inputs with microseconds.

Here you can see the whole wiring scheme I created. I only had Paint in my hand so please excuse me for not having any technical electrical scheme.

[image: Text]

Basically, the LiPo powers the Rx, servos, ESC, and brushless motor; while the signal cables are connected to the microprocessor which is powered by the USB cable. I read and write data for debugging and testing from console commands.

I then do not edit the data, I basically re-write the channel inputs only reversing if necessary. I create PWM signals 250 Hz for all of the components.

Here is my whole code with explanations:

```
// LIBRARIES USED
  #include "deneyap.h"
  #include <Wire.h>

//PIN SETTINGS
  const int BZRpin = D0; //inout pin for buzzer
  const int PPMpin = D1; //pinout for ppm
  const int RightAileronPin = D12;
  const int LeftAileronPin = D13;
  const int ElevatorPin = D14;
  const int ThrottlePin = D4;
  const int RudderPin = D15;

//CHANNEL ASSIGNMENTS
  const int RightAileronCH = 1;
  const int LeftAileronCH = 1; // must be negative value (reversed)
  const int ElevatorCH = 2;
  const int ThrottleCH = 3;
  const int RudderCH = 4;

//RC INPUT SETTINGS
  const int channelNum = 8; //num of channels inputed - PUBLIC

//PPM SETTINGS
  volatile long PW[channelNum] = {0}; //        array of pulse-width of channels in micro sec PRIVATE
  volatile long ptime = 0; //                                specific pulse time in micro sec PRIVATE
  volatile long crtime = 0; //                                      current time in micro sec PRIVATE
  volatile int pulse = 0; //                                        num of encountered pulses PRIVATE

//RC OUTPUT SETTINGS
  float ThrottleInput;
  float RightAileronInput;
  float LeftAileronInput;
  float ElevatorInput;
  float RudderInput;
  float TestServoInput;

//MPU SETTINGS
  float RateROLL, RatePITCH, RateYAW;
  float ROLLcal, PITCHcal, YAWcal;
  int NUMcal; // private
  const int NUMtotalcal = 4000;

// MAIN METHOD
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(57600); // initlize serial com

  pinMode(BZRpin, OUTPUT); // buzzer initiated

  pinMode(RightAileronPin, OUTPUT);   // pins for servos for Right Aileron initiated
  pinMode(LeftAileronPin, OUTPUT);    // pins for servos for Left Aileroninitiated
  pinMode(ElevatorPin, OUTPUT);       // pins for servos for Elevator initiated
  pinMode(RudderPin, OUTPUT);         // pins for servos for Rudder initiated
  pinMode(ThrottlePin,OUTPUT);        // pins for ESC for Throttle initiated
  
  Serial.print("Please wait...");

  //PWM setup
  analogWriteFrequency(250);
  analogWriteResolution(12);
  delay(250);

  //Set control surfaces to safe oriantation for pre-flight
  analogWrite(RightAileronPin,1.024*1500);
  analogWrite(LeftAileronPin,1.024*1500);
  analogWrite(ElevatorPin,1.024*1500);
  analogWrite(RudderPin,1.024*1500);
  delay(2000);

  //system message on power
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.println("SYSTEM POWERED");
  Serial.println("==============");
  buzzersig(200);
  buzzersig(200);
  delay(1000);

  //--------------- CONFIGURATIONS -----------------//
    Serial.println("- Configuring settings -");
    delay(500);

    Serial.print("MPU (I2C Settings)..."); // Settings for MPU I2C Com.
    
      Wire.setClock(400000); //I2C 
      Wire.begin();
      delay(250);
      Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
      Wire.write(0x6B);
      Wire.write(0x00);
      Wire.endTransmission();
    
      Serial.println("DONE");
    delay(500);

    /*
    Serial.print("Calibrqation 2")        //desc
      
      //cal

      Serial.println("DONE");
    delay(500);
    */

    Serial.println("SUCCESS!");
    buzzersig(200);
    Serial.println(" ");
    delay(500);

  //---------------- CALIBRATIONS ------------------//
    Serial.println("- Sensor Calibrations - (INITIATING)!");
    delay(500);

    Serial.print("Calculating IMU - Do not touch the platform!");
      delay(2000);
      buzzersig(500);

      for(NUMcal = 0; NUMcal < NUMtotalcal; NUMcal++) {
        gyro_sig();
        ROLLcal+= RateROLL;
        PITCHcal+= RatePITCH;
        YAWcal+= RateYAW;
        delay(1);
        if(NUMcal%1000 == 0 ) {
          Serial.print(".");
          buzzersig(100);
        }
      }
      ROLLcal/=NUMtotalcal;
      PITCHcal/=NUMtotalcal;
      YAWcal/=NUMtotalcal;

      Serial.println("DONE");
    delay(500);

    /*
    Serial.print("Calculating X - Do not touch the platform!");
      delay(2000);
      buzzersig(500);

      cal 2

      Serial.println("DONE");
    delay(500);
    */

    Serial.println("SUCCESS!");
    buzzersig(200);
    Serial.println(" ");
    delay(500);
  //system message on succesful Initialization
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.println("SYSTEMS INITIATED");
  Serial.println("================");
  buzzersig(200);
  buzzersig(200);
  buzzersig(200);

  //Inıtiated PPM Reading functions
  delay(500);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PPMpin), ppmread, FALLING); // Attach interrupt to pin for reading PPM channels.
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.println("Waiting for Tx Signal! (CH1 is sampling)");

  while(PW[0] < 900 || PW[0] > 2100) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
    Serial.print(PW[0]);
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.println("CONNECTED!");
  buzzersig(200);

  //safety for microporcessor resets 
  while(PW[ThrottleCH-1] > 1020  ) {
    delay(4);

    Serial.println("ATTENTION!! LOWER THE THROTTLE STICK!!");
    Serial.print(PW[ThrottleCH-1]);
    Serial.print("[/µs] ");

    Serial.println();
    buzzersig(200);
    //delay(200);
  }

  //electronically starting the burshless motors
  /*
  analogWriteFrequency(250);
  buzzersig(200);
  analogWrite(ThrottlePin,1.024*1000);
  delay(200);
  analogWrite(ThrottlePin,1.024*2000);
  delay(200);
  analogWrite(ThrottlePin,1.024*1000);
  delay(2000);
  */
}

void loop() {

  gyro_sig(); // get gyro data and apply calibration
    RateROLL-=ROLLcal;
    RatePITCH-=PITCHcal;
    RateYAW-=YAWcal;
  /*
    Serial.print("ROLL r: ");
    Serial.print(RateROLL);
    Serial.print(" PITCH r: ");
    Serial.print(RatePITCH);
    Serial.print(" YAW r: ");
    Serial.println(RateYAW);
    delay(50);
    /*
    7*
    for (int i =0 ; i<channelNum; i++) {
      Serial.print("Ch");
      Serial.print(i+1);
      Serial.print(": ");
      if(i==7)
      {
        Serial.println(PW[i]);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print(PW[i]);
        Serial.print("  ");
      }
      
    }
  */
  //write throttle to ESC
  if(PW[ThrottleCH-1] < 1030) 
  { //prevents twitching
    ThrottleInput = 1.024*1000;
    analogWrite(ThrottlePin, (ThrottleInput));
  }
  else 
  { //applies throttle    
    ThrottleInput = 1.024*PW[ThrottleCH-1];
    analogWrite(ThrottlePin, (ThrottleInput));
  }

  //write Right Aileron
    RightAileronInput = 1.024*PW[RightAileronCH-1];
    analogWrite(RightAileronPin, (RightAileronInput));

  //write Left Aileron
    LeftAileronInput = 1.024*map(PW[LeftAileronCH-1],1000,2000,2000,1000);
    analogWrite(LeftAileronPin, (LeftAileronInput));

  //write Rudder
    RudderInput = 1.024*PW[RudderCH-1];
    analogWrite(RudderPin, (RudderInput));
    
  //write Elevator
    ElevatorInput = 1.024*PW[ElevatorCH-1];
    analogWrite(ElevatorPin, (ElevatorInput));

  /*
    Input = 1.024*PW[CH-1];
    analogWrite(Pin, (Input));
  */
    //prints out channel inputs for debugging
      for(int j=0; j<channelNum; j++) {
        Serial.print("CH");
        Serial.print(j+1);
        Serial.print(": ");
        if(j==7)
        {
          Serial.println(PW[j]);
        }
        else
        {
          Serial.print(PW[j]);
          Serial.print("  ");
        }
      }
      delay(4);
}

void ppmread() { //interrupt method

  switch (pulse) {
    default: 
      pulse++;
      ptime = micros();
    break;

    case 1:
      crtime = micros();
      PW[pulse-1] = crtime - ptime;
      pulse++;
      ptime = crtime;
      if (PW[pulse-2]>2100) {
        pulse = 1;
      }
    break;

    case 2:
      crtime = micros();
      PW[pulse-1] = crtime - ptime;
      pulse++;
      ptime = crtime;
      if (PW[pulse-2]>2100) {
        pulse = 1;
      } 
    break;

    case 3:
      crtime = micros();
      PW[pulse-1] = crtime - ptime;
      pulse++;
      ptime = crtime;
      if (PW[pulse-2]>2100) {
        pulse = 1;
      }
    break;

    case 4:
      crtime = micros();
      PW[pulse-1] = crtime - ptime;
      pulse++;
      ptime = crtime;
      if (PW[pulse-2]>2100) {
        pulse = 1;
      }
    break;

    case 5:
      crtime = micros();
      PW[pulse-1] = crtime - ptime;
      pulse++;
      ptime = crtime;
      if (PW[pulse-2]>2100) {
        pulse = 1;
      }
    break;

    case 6:
      crtime = micros();
      PW[pulse-1] = crtime - ptime;
      pulse++;
      ptime = crtime;
      if (PW[pulse-2]>2100) {
        pulse = 1;
      }
    break;

    case 7:
      crtime = micros();
      PW[pulse-1] = crtime - ptime;
      pulse++;
      ptime = crtime;
      if (PW[pulse-2]>2100) {
        pulse = 1;
      }
    break;

    case 8:
      crtime = micros();
      PW[pulse-1] = crtime - ptime;
      pulse = 0;
      ptime = crtime;
      if (PW[pulse+channelNum-1]>2100) {
        pulse = 1;
      }
    break;
  }
}

void buzzersig(int ms) {
    digitalWrite(BZRpin,HIGH);
    delay(ms);
    digitalWrite(BZRpin,LOW);
    delay(ms);
}

void gyro_sig() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1A);
  Wire.write(0x05);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1B);
  Wire.write(0x8);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x43);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,6);
  int16_t GyroX=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t GyroY=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t GyroZ=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();

  RateROLL=(float)GyroX/65.5;
  RatePITCH=(float)GyroY/65.5;
  RateYAW=(float)GyroZ/65.5;
}
```

There are a few other codes for system initialization etc. Do not mind them.

The whole system works fine, BUT I have a persistent issue:
The problem I cannot solve is that whenever I start moving servos a bit fast, the brushless motors start "twitching" moving and spinning sometimes.

I have tried writing the channel values and the variable ( ThrottleInput float) I input for the esc in the form of a PWM signal. I see that I input the lowest input, BUT SOMEHOW motor still spins and "twitches" to this day.

Note for PPM signalling: 1000 microseconds (lowest, min input) for CH length in PPM pulse, I convert it in the code to a form that can be inputted as an arg in analogWrite, so I have a PWM wave at the end.

I have observed that:

- Only motor experiences such behaviour. Not other servos.
- More vigorously the servo channel input from the transmitter, Tx, (moving sticks faster to left and right) the spinning of the motor movement increases and becomes more significant.
- I have read about servos exceeding 5 V and creating voltage spikes (mine are 4.8 - 5.3 depending on the way I move them through Tx, I measured.) may be causing this problem.
  I have talked with a professor from a university (a professional) and he stated that the problem could be caused by using the same ground for signalling and powering.

I need the USB cable for reading data until I finish this project. I have ordered I PCB for a more streamlined 5V output (BEC integrated PDB). Do I need to power everything from LiPo? I will be unable to use USB when the system is powered on, I do not want this.

Please I wish urgent help.

Update: Here's the list of my current suspicions:

- I have been thinking about grounding loops, maybe grounding the microprocessor to my PC and ESC, servos and Motor to the battery unintentionally.
- Not using a ferrite ring, which typically most RC hobbyist use in their ESC, yet know nothing about them. Has to do with voltage spikes and stuff.

I have also talked with other professionals and some forum members. They have stated that servos, when working, create some sort of "voltage spikes, "backwards current" and some EMF so a diode must be in use, yet I have no idea how to place the component into the current electrical scheme.

Also, original Arduino Forums post: [click here!](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/twitching-burshless-motor-when-rc-pwm-servo-input-given-through-microprocessor/1203372)

Comment: PWM controlled things twitching often means that the PWM waveform isn't stable... can you inspect or verify it with any tools (even a dedicated arduino if that's what you have available)

Comment: Greetings @Attie, I tried to print out the `ThrottleInput` variable after I write it to ESC to drive the servo as a PWM signal. It seems that the software inputs the correct variable, in somewhat correct magnitude, (probably I need to calibrate the channel readings manually before using the data, and some errors in reading ofc.) 
When I move the servos, the digital software Input microprocessor outputs stays the same. However, from an analogue/electricity perspective, it isn't. So maybe it is about a sort of short circuit, or leakage of voltage/current towards BLDC motor from servos?